# Method of interpolation to create weighted heatmap rasters in R from point data

Tags: r, interpolation, rasterization, heat-map, plotting

I want to create a geospatial heatmap that is weighted by a specific variable sourced from georeferenced points.

An example dataset is '*us_states*' from the '*spData*' package. I want to take this data, create a centroid for each state polygon, then use interpolation between centroids to create a heatmap for total population in year 2015. I took the first few steps to get there and then hit a wall.

Here is code I used to get to where I am now:

```
# load packages

library(spData)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

# extract data and quickly plot it for visual confirmation

data("us_states")

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = us_states)
```

```
# extract centroids and visualize with polygons

us_states_centroid <- st_centroid(us_states$geometry)  

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = us_states2) +
  geom_sf(data = us_states_centroid) + 
  theme_bw()
```

```
# add centroid data to original polygon file as latitude and longitude

us_states$centroid <- st_centroid(us_states$geometry)
centroid_XY <- as.data.frame(st_coordinates(us_states$centroid)) 
us_states$lat <- centroid_XY$Y
us_states$lon <- centroid_XY$X

# create a geopackage with this information

st_write(us_states, 
         dsn = "data/us_states.gpkg", layer = "us_states_polygon",
         delete_layer = T)
st_write(us_states_centroid, 
         dsn = "data/us_states.gpkg", layer = "us_states_centroid", 
         delete_layer = T)
```

I am not aware of an intuitive process for weighted interpolation in R. Therefore, I took the data to QGIS and used interpolation to create the heatmap depicted in the image below:

[image: qgis heatmap]

When using R, how would I create a weighted heatmap using the kernal density estimation method (with a quartic kernal shape)? My goal is to:

- Plot heatmap in R using using geographic coordinates for points and either continuous scale (liner from 0-40,000,000 population) or discrete scale (10 equal levels from 0-40,000,000 population) for the heatmap interpolation

Feel free to use a different example dataset if you prefer. I am aware that QGIS or ArcGIS are easier softwares for creating maps, but R offers tools that I also want to use. I am not an expert at either software and this is an exercise to increase my proficiency with R.

Comment: You've asked for a few things - kernel density estimation (weighted or otherwise) is not the same as a spatial interpolation using IDW or otherwise. There are R packages for both, for example `gstat` does spatial interpolation via kriging or IDW.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. We are not a discussion forum. Instead we use a Focused question / Best answer model. Advice requests are also *off-topic* here. In theory, [Chat] exists for this sort of *discussion-oriented* topic, but Chat has a minimum reputation requirement, and does not see the volume of users of the main stack here.

Comment: For someone who may be searching for an answer to this question, I found a webpage that explains the kernel method and IDW method of interpolation in R: https://rspatial.org/raster/analysis/4-interpolation.html. It's the most intuitive method I found so far. I hope there may be more streamline methods or interpolation in the future. I may update this post later with an answer to the original question.